# Using "As" at beginning of a sentence

Tags: phrases, sentence, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

A company called Goodbrothers (for the sake of argument) wants to advertise its environmental credentials, using

> As Goodbrothers, we always pay attention to environmental concerns.

In this context, is it possible to use *as* at the beginning of a sentence?

Comment: Don't you mean "as **a** company ..."?

Comment: In fact, I mean "As the Company, we ....". Or the name of company "As CompanyABC, we ..."

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your question, then.

Comment: All it means is *at* GB we always... You can't mean doing business as GB, we are environmental, but as XYZ, not so much.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "AS" in that context, but I think "AT" is a better choice.

At GOODBROTHERS, we always pay attention to environmental concerns.

Imo.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. We do like answers to be supported by more than just opinion. **Why** is *at* a better choice? *As* is a preposition which can be used in an introductory clause like "As a nail, it's very useful."

Comment: I would like my answers to be better supported, but I don't possess a technical lexicon of English terms and parts